# Moving pie chart in Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine for creating piecharts in android. Now everything is going fine except that my pie chart can be dragged/moved to anywhere within the layout. I want my pie chart to be fixed at its own location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `renderer.setPanEnabled(false);` on the `DefaultRenderer` object.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to disable the pinch zoom together with the pan:

```
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
```